# R shiny / shiny-server - issue with finding packages

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have installed shiny and shiny-server on an ubuntu server. I did a similar install on a dev server which is working. R sessions when they open up load some packages. The app runs fine locally but I'm getting messages that it can't find the packages when running on shiny-server.

The error on the app

```
During startup - Warning messages:

1: In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘shiny’
2: package ‘shiny’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
3: In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘data.table’
4: package ‘data.table’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
5: In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘optiRum’
6: package ‘optiRum’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  The Shiny package was not found in the library. Ensure that 
Shiny is installed and is available in the Library of the 
user you're running this application as.
Calls: local -> eval.parent -> eval -> eval -> eval -> eval
Execution halted
```

In Rprofile.site I have

```
# ## Example of Rprofile.site
 local({
#  # add MASS to the default packages, set a CRAN mirror
  old <- getOption("defaultPackages"); r <- getOption("repos")
#  r["CRAN"] <- "http://my.local.cran"
  options(defaultPackages = c(old, "shiny","data.table","optiRum"), repos = r)
})

.First <- function() {
   cat("\n   Welcome to R!\n\n")
#    setwd("/home/OPTIMUMCREDIT/R/Projects")
    Sys.umask(mode="0002")
}
.libPaths(c("/home/R/WorkingPackages","/home/R/ApprovedPackages"))
```

In shiny-server config I have just the default config  (so run as shiny and default port).

My sessionInfo()

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=C         LC_TIME=C            LC_COLLATE=C         LC_MONETARY=C        LC_MESSAGES=C        LC_PAPER=C          
 [8] LC_NAME=C            LC_ADDRESS=C         LC_TELEPHONE=C       LC_MEASUREMENT=C     LC_IDENTIFICATION=C 

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_0.9.3.1  scales_0.2.3     RCurl_1.95-4.1   bitops_1.0-6     rstudio_0.98.501 optiRum_0.30     data.table_1.9.2 shiny_0.8.0     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] MASS_7.3-29        RColorBrewer_1.0-5 RJSONIO_1.0-3      Rcpp_0.11.0        caTools_1.16       colorspace_1.2-4   dichromat_2.0-0   
 [8] digest_0.6.4       grid_3.0.3         gtable_0.1.2       httpuv_1.2.3       labeling_0.2       munsell_0.4.2      plyr_1.8.1        
[15] proto_0.3-10       reshape2_1.2.2     stringr_0.6.2      tools_3.0.3        xtable_1.7-3
```

I tried adding a message to output the libPaths above `library(shiny)` in my code but unfortunately the same error message happens. I did some uninstalling and reinstalling as I'd a bit unusually installed shiny-server first then remembered I needed shiny but no joy. I've confirmed that shiny is installed in ApprovedPackages.  The packages at load up, I added in the hopes of circumventing the problem or finding out more information.

**UPDATE - running as shiny**
Ah - the plot thickens... logging in with the user shiny on console caused the same warnings the app was getting, and .libPaths() is not like everyone else's:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
> .libPaths()
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib/R/site-library"
[3] "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

**I'm a bit stumped and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction to solve the problem.**

Comment: Is this similar to your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16065805/packages-missing-in-shiny-server?rq=1

Comment: I looked at it, but since all packages are installed to one of two centrally defined paths that are detailed in the Rprofile.site, I didn't think it would be pertinent. Running `sudo R` does not get the same issue - I can load packages no problem.

Comment: Can you login as shiny (`sudo su shiny`), open R, and print out the `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: Done, Rpofile.site .libPaths doesn't appear to be applied for the shiny user.

Comment: I'd be looking to see if the `/home/R/WorkingPackages` and `ApprovedPackages` were accessible to the Shiny user -- perhaps other users are all members of some group that `shiny` is not, so it can't get in. Or perhaps the `Rprofile.site` or one of its parent directories has such a problem?

Comment: Also, if you wanted to cheat... you could just login as `shiny`, open R, and install the Shiny package there. I would say that's probably not the most stable long-term solution, but should get you rolling now if you get tired of fighting this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sorry for the troubles. Can you try running the following command to install Shiny system-wide?

```
sudo su - \
  -c "R -e \"install.packages('shiny', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')\""
```

This comes from the [Admin Guide](http://rstudio.github.io/shiny-server/latest/#ubuntu-12.04) which (hopefully) will serve as a useful resource on these kinds of issues.

I suspect that the problem is that Shiny is indeed properly installed in your user account, but because it wasn't installed as sudo, it's *not* available to the `shiny` user.

Edits:

You'll also need to make sure that `Rprofile.site` is being applied when the `shiny` user starts an R process. You can do this by logging in as `shiny`:

```
sudo su shiny
```

Then opening R and checking the `.libPaths()` or seeing if you can successfully run `library(shiny)` there. If you're not able to, there's probably an issue with letting the `shiny` user get into your shared packages directory or your `Rprofile.site` file (or its parent directory). Ensure that the `shiny` user is added to the necessary groups or that these files and all of their parent directories grant the appropriate permissions to the `shiny` user.

Comment: How to let the shiny user get into the shared package directory?