# Unable to load installed packages in shiny server using renv

Tags: r, shiny, package, shiny-server, renv

I have several large shiny apps which perfectly work on my local computer, but do not on my shiny server as it seems impossible to load most of the installed packages.

I work with the package `renv` since I want to avoid dependency problems between the packages used in the different shiny apps. So all my nessecary packages are contained within a folder `renv` from which I want to load them to run my app:

[image]

Minimal working example:

```
# change path to library
.libPaths("/home/yvs/ShinyApps/test2/renv/library/R-3.6/x86_64-w64-mingw32")

# load packages
library(shiny)
library(DBI)
library(RPostgreSQL)
library(shinyalert)

# run app
shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
      column(4,
        numericInput("x", "Value", 5),
        br(),
        actionButton("button", "test"),
        br(),
        textOutput("text")
      ),
      column(8, 
        tableOutput("table")),
        useShinyalert()
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
      observeEvent(input$button, {
        cat("Showing", input$x, "rows\n")
        shinyalert("yeah!")
      })
      df <- eventReactive(input$button, {
        head(cars, input$x)
      })
      output$table <- renderTable({
        df()
      })
      output$text <- renderText(
        paste0(.libPaths()) # display path to library
    )
    }
)
```

This error message appears in my log-file when I call the corresponding http-page:

```
Fehler: package or namespace load failed for â€˜RPostgreSQLâ€™ in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):
 shared object â€˜RPostgreSQL.soâ€™ not found
AusfÃ¼hrung angehalten
```

When I mark `library(RPostgreSQL)` as comment, I can run the app with no error.
Since all packages `shiny`, `DBI`, `RPostgreSQL` and `shinyalert` are only available within my renv-folder (and not within the default shiny library), I assume that loading packages via the command `.libPaths()` seems to work. Thus, I don't think it is only a permission problem (I do not owe admin rights or the permission to run/log in as user *shiny*.

Moreover I do not think that this problem is limited to the package `RPostgreSQL` as I attempted to load many different packages.

It worked with the following packages:
`shiny` `leaflet` `stats` `utils` `graphics` `DBI` `shinycssloaders` `shinyalert` `shinyjs` `DT`.

It did not work with the following packages:
`sp` `plotly` `RPostgreSQL` `postGIStools` `dplyr` `lubridate` `devtools` `rCharts` `rjson` `yaml` `config`.

I am aware of at least the following two similar issues:

- [Packages missing in shiny-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16065805/packages-missing-in-shiny-server)
- [R shiny / shiny-server - issue with finding packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22298187/r-shiny-shiny-server-issue-with-finding-packages?noredirect=1&lq=1)

However, neither of them helped to solve my problems.

Both my local computer and the shiny server use R 3.6.3.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: How did you install packages to the server?  Also, the OS of the server and your computer may help.

Comment: well, actually I just copied my renv-folder (containing all the packages) to the filesystem of my server. this might not be a proper installation, but since roughly 50% of the packages could be loaded that way i assume it still seems to work.
I work with windows10.

Comment: I see.  Do you have no right to install packages on the server?  If you can, that would be a safer option.  If the dependency is your concern, you can install with `install.packages(..., lib=...)` to specify a package folder for each app.

Comment: If installation on the server is not an option, the error seems to be related to loading compiled code (`*.so` file), and the successful libraries seem those do not load one (I quickly checked `library(<packagename>` and then `library.dynam()`).  One thing you can check is which .so file your local computer is reading and what file the R on the server is looking for.

Comment: I found that my server is indeed looking for these complied file in the wrong place. According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41494585/setting-ld-library-path-from-inside-r I tried to load the necessary file by ```dyn.load("/home/yvs/ShinyApps/test2/renv/library/R-3.6/x86_64-w64-mingw32/RPostgreSQL/libs/x64/RPostgreSQL.dll")```. However, it gives me an error saying it to be an *invalid ELF header*. So maybe there is no other solution than proper installation on the server as shiny/admin.