# Unable to deploy Shiny application on Shiny Server in Linux VM

Tags: r, linux, rhel, shiny-server, rhel6

I have been trying to deploy my shiny application in shiny server which i have installed on Linux VM (RHEL 6.5, 64 bit) by following the instructions given in this [site](https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/download-server/)

The server is started successfully but i get the following when i try to access the sample application provided as a part of the shiny server.

> Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
>   unable to load shared object '/usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so':
>   /usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so: invalid ELF header
>
> In addition: Warning message: 
>   package ‘shiny’ was built under R version 3.3.0
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘shiny’ Execution halted
>   I installed all the required packages without any error still i got this exception when i tried to access the sample application.

The following are the steps i followed to install shiny server.

1. Installed R. In my office EPEL repository is blocked since it is maintained by a third party organization. So I downloaded the rpm file for R from EPEL [website](https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/repoview/letter_r.group.html) and installed the same using the rpm command.
2. Next i downloaded the shiny package from the [CRAN repository](https://cran.r-project.org/) and installed the same using the following command
      R CMD INSTALL shiny_0.13.2.tgz
3. Finally i downloaded and installed the shiny server RPM file.

The server was successfully installed and started without any errors, yet i get the above error when trying to access the application deployed in the server.

I googled a lot for this error but could not find much. Has anybody else faced this issue? Could someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue. I installed all the packages as root user but shiny server runs under a different username "shiny". In order to solve this I started an R session using the following command

```
sudo R
```

Then I installed the packages using their source, as my LINUX VM (office machine)did not have internet access. I used the following command for installing the packages from the source. First we need to untar the source and then run the following command.

```
require(devtools)
install('path-to-the-untared-folder')
```

The below link helped me in finding out the solution.

[R - shiny server on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22696363/r-shiny-server-on-ubuntu?rq=1)