# Unable to load 'digest' package on a shiny server during application initialisation

Tags: r, shiny, golem

I have a shiny application that I try to deploy on a shiny server. I am using the package golem.

I get this error in my browser :

```
An error has occurred

The application failed to start.

The application exited during initialization.
```

I get this error in the logs:

```
su: ignore --preserve-environment, it's mutually exclusive to --login.
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘digest’
Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

I installed the package and can load it from my server console

I did check :

```
> .Library
[1] "/tmp/Rtmp0j1ghM/renv-system-library"


# and 

> .libPaths()
[1] "/var/www/others/formations_vne/shiny/vigie-analyse/renv/library/R-4.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
[2] "/tmp/Rtmp0j1ghM/renv-system-library"
```

and digest is in both :

```
/vigie-analyse/renv/library/R-4.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu# ls
anytime      curl     ggplot2      labeling     ps        scales          tidyselect
askpass      data.table   gh           later        purrr     selectr         tinytex
attempt      desc     gitcreds     lifecycle    R6        sessioninfo         urlchecker
base64enc    devtools     glue         magrittr     ragg      shiny           usethis
BH       diffobj      golem        memoise      rappdirs      shinyBS         utf8
blastula     digest   gtable       mime     rcmdcheck     shinydashboard      uuid
brew         downlit      here         miniUI       RColorBrewer  shinydashboardPlus  vctrs
brio         dplyr    highr        munsell      Rcpp      shinyjs         viridisLite
bslib        ellipsis     htmltools    openssl      rematch2      shinyWidgets        waiter
cachem       evaluate     htmlwidgets  pillar       remotes   sourcetools         waldo
callr        fansi    httpuv       pkgbuild     renv      spelling        webshot
cli      farver   httr         pkgconfig    rlang     stringi         whisker
clipr        fastmap      hunspell     pkgdown      rmarkdown     stringr         withr
colorspace   fontawesome  ini          pkgload      roxygen2      svglite         xfun
commonmark   fresh    isoband      praise       rprojroot     sys             xml2
config       fs       jquerylib    prettyunits  rstudioapi    systemfonts         xopen
cpp11        generics     jsonlite     processx     rversions     testthat        xtable
crayon       gert     kableExtra   profvis      rvest     textshaping         yaml
credentials  getPass      knitr        promises     sass      tibble          zip


/tmp/Rtmp0j1ghM/renv-system-library# ls
base   cluster    datasets  graphics   KernSmooth  Matrix   nlme      rpart    stats     tcltk
boot   codetools  digest    grDevices  lattice     methods  nnet      spatial  stats4    tools
class  compiler   foreign   grid       MASS    mgcv     parallel  splines  survival  utils
```

I really don't understand why I cannot access this package. Does anyone as an idea ?

Answer (score 2):

If you run aplication in shiny server, they are run by *shiny* user which means that path to deafult libraries may also be different. To see what *shiny* user has access to, you can deploy simple app, that will write to text file output of

`.libPaths()`

and

`rownames(installed.packages())`.

Comment: This was a very good idea! I did this test application and ```digest``` is within the installed packages. I updated my post to include another information. It fails during initialisation.

Comment: Could that be of any help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57449443/8307260

Comment: It is interesting but didn't solve it. I still can't find this package...

Comment: My user "shiny" can load ```digest``` without any trouble

Comment: What was the solution?

Comment: I don't have a solution. I installed everything for the user but I still get the same error...